# sql WHERE clause not working properly

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, where-clause, clause

I am new to Java and sql. I have written a where clause however it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
"SELECT Threat_Hazard_ID FROM Threats_Hazards_Categories WHERE Hazard = '" + hz + "'";
```

based on a selection in a previous comboBox "hz", I want to pull the ID I've given it. Yet it seems to just kick back the selection which was made.

here is the section of code I have written, fill free to offer better methods of performing this task.

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        try {
            Object hz = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(hz);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MAAWB.db");
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String Hid = "SELECT Threat_Hazard_ID FROM Threats_Hazards_Categories WHERE Hazard = '" + hz + "'";
            hidtest = stmt.executeQuery(Hid);
            int test = hidtest.getInt("Threat_Hazzard_ID");
            String hazardCP = "SELECT HazardCP FROM Hazard_CP WHERE Threat_Hazard_Id = " + Hid;
            if(radioButton.isSelected() != false) {
                while(hcp.next()){
                    Hcp = hcp.getString("HazardCP");
                    comboBox_1.removeItem(Tcp);
                    comboBox_1.addItem(Hcp);
```

Comment: replace  String obj = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: And    Hazard = ' " + hz+ " '  ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
String Hid = "SELECT Threat_Hazard_ID FROM Threats_Hazards_Categories WHERE Hazard = '" + hz + "'";
```

To

```
String Hid = "SELECT           Threat_Hazard_ID FROM Threats_Hazards_Categories WHERE Hazard = '" + hz.toString()+ "'";
```

Comment: wow that was simple, thanks for the help. Not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

Object hz = comboBox.getSelectedItem();

"hz" is a reference object here not a String. However in your SQL, you are using it as a String object (trying to concatenate).

String Hid = "SELECT Threat_Hazard_ID FROM Threats_Hazards_Categories WHERE Hazard = '" + hz + "'";

You need to use the String value of "hz" (selected item as a String) and then it should work I hope. Also, look into what has been inserted in the combobox (a String?). You will get Whatever type of an object has been inserted in the Combobox at the first place. If it is not a String then you need to first get the String value from the inserted items. You can try this:

String hz = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();

But it all depends on the items inserted to combobox at the first place.